# webpack 5 with babel build not exporting functions

Tags: npm, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader, webpack-5

I am trying to build and publish a react component to npm. I am using webpack 5 with babel. The build succeeds, but when I try use the component it is aparent that the component is not being exported as I get the following error in the console:

```
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at App.js:41.
    at App
```

My project structure looks like this:

```
- src/
    - components/
        - MyComponent.js
    - styles/
        - MyComponent.css
    - index.js
- .babelrc
- package.json
- webpack.config.js
```

MyComponent.js contains the following:

```js
import '../styles/MyComponent.css'

export default function MyComponentFunction() {
    return (
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    )
}
```

My index.js file contains the following:

```
import MyComponentFunction from './components/MyComponent'
export default {
    MyComponentFunction
}
```

My .babelrc file contains the following:

```json
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env","@babel/preset-react" ]
}
```

My webpack.config.js contains the following:

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
 output: {
   path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
   filename: 'index.bundle.js',
   libraryTarget: 'umd'
 },
 module: {
   rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      use: {
        loader:'babel-loader',
      },
      exclude: /node_modules/
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader'
      ],
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }
   ]
 }
}
```

And my package.json (which includes lots of unused libraries) contains the following:

```json
{
  "name": "my-component",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A react component ...",
  "main": "dist/index.bundle.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    ...
  },
  "keywords": [
  ],
  "author": "<Author>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "<github repo>"
  },
  "homepage": "<github repo>#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-three/drei": "^9.36.0",
    "@react-three/fiber": "^8.8.10",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "three": "^0.145.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

Why can I not import my component after it has been published? Which i'm trying to do like so:

```
import {MyComponentFunction} from 'my-component'

function App() {

  return (
    <>
    <MyComponentFunction></MyComponentFunction>
    </>
    
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are facing this issue is that you have named the package as an exact match for [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/my-component). The name must be unique.